# Multi forms with selects but all $_POST are overwritten with last $_POST

Tags: html, post

In below test code I try to **save and use 3 $_POST variables**. But only the last $_POST variable is stored. The rest is overwritten with the last $_POST variable.
Purpose of the question is to select first the wanted country. Select from a table the country as selected. Then select the wanted a car_brand from the selected country. Then select the wanted company and filter this from the selected country+car_brand.

I have tried to store the 3 $_POST into a $_SESSION also tried it with $_REQUEST via type="hidden" without getting the 3 $_POST variables.

> Question: what do I do wrong and how can I solve this problem?

```
session_start();
$content .= ' <form id="sel_country" method="POST">
<select name="country" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="DE">German</option>
    <option value="GB">England</option> 
</select> 
</form>';

$content .= '<form id="sel_car_brand" method="POST">
<select name="brand" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>  
</select> 
</form>';

$content .= ' <form id="sel_company" method="POST">
<select name="company" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="dealer">Dealer</option>
    <option value="service">Service</option>
    <option value="import">Importer</option>                    
</select>
</form>';

$_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
$_SESSION['brand'] = $_POST['brand'];
$_SESSION['company'] = $_POST['company'];

var_dump($_SESSION) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a session_start() at the beginning and then stock your variable in it. Like $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'] when $_POST['country'] is defined (do a var_dump() to verify it) and you'll be able to access your datas stocked in your $_SESSION.

```
session_start();
$content .= ' <form id="sel_country" method="POST">
<select name="country" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="DE">German</option>
    <option value="GB">England</option> 
</select> 
</form>';

$_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];

$content .= '<form id="sel_car_brand" method="POST">
<select name="brand" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>  
</select> 
</form>';

$_SESSION['brand'] = $_POST['brand'];

$content .= ' <form id="sel_company" method="POST">
<select name="company" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="dealer">Dealer</option>
    <option value="service">Service</option>
    <option value="import">Importer</option>                    
</select>
</form>';

$_SESSION['company'] = $_POST['company'];

var_dump($_SESSION) ;
// Edited by moliets: var_dump response: array(3) { ["country"]=> NULL ["brand"]=> NULL ["company"]=> string(6) "import" }
```

Comment: I have change the example with your suggestions. Also no result. Only last $_SESSION is filled correct. See code above,
array(6) { ["company1"]=> string(0) "" ["car_brand1"]=> string(0) "" ["company"]=> string(6) "import" ["country"]=> NULL ["car_brand"]=> NULL ["brand"]=> NULL }

Comment: What about with
`session_start();
$content .= ' <form id="sel_country" method="POST">
    <select name="country" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
        <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
        <option value="DE">German</option>
        <option value="GB">England</option> 
    </select> 
</form>';
    
$_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
$content .= '<form id="sel_car_brand" method="POST">`
etc...

Comment: same result. I have placed  session_start(); at the top as it should be. only 1 $_SESSION is stored.

Comment: Yes. Moved each  $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country']; etc. below each select. My code above is strictly the same as on my dev site.

Comment: Easy question (but sometimes, it's with easy things you can solve problems^^"): Did you clear your cache after your changes?

Comment: Is your project on a github or other repo to be able to test it locally?